# Changing to two environment using one APK

Tags: java, android, apk

we are developing android app and there are two different environment that we need to point separately. lets say it staging and production but due to compliance requirement we need to provide one apk file and there should be a way to change environment
when its required so that they can make sure that same file go production that they tested on staging.

We are keeping url details in string.xml and normally we give two apks pointing to two diferent environment.

so we are just wandering is there any tool or any other method that we can change string.xml values inside apk. So that they can use that tool to
change url when they required.

Comment: Use shared preferences to save env and load based on it. you have to take input from user which env to use runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Use this kind of way to separate the urls,

```
buildTypes {
debug {
    buildConfigField "Boolean", "IS_DEBUG", 'true'
    buildConfigField "String", "URL", 'https://appsgit.com/debugurl'
}

release {
    buildConfigField "Boolean", "IS_DEBUG", 'false'
    buildConfigField "String", "URL", 'https://appsgit.com/releaseurl'
}
```

}

Please check this [blog post](https://appsgit.com/efficiently-use-gradle-android/) for more info..

If this solution doesn't work. You can try **Gradle BuildFlavor**.

Add ProductFlavor like below (Free & Paid).

```
productFlavors {
free {
    applicationId "com.appsgit.freeapp"
    buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_PAID', 'false'
    buildConfigField 'boolean', 'URL', 'http://freeversion.com'
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, output.outputFile.name.replace("app-release.apk", "app-free-" + defaultConfig.versionName + ".apk"))
        }
    }
}

paid {
    applicationId "com.appsgit.paidapp"
    buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_PAID', 'true'
    buildConfigField 'boolean', 'URL', 'https://paidversion.com'
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, output.outputFile.name.replace("app-release.apk", "app-paid-" + defaultConfig.versionName + ".apk"))
        }
    }
}
```

}

And create code base like here,

[image]

Don't forget `Main` is shared to all the flavors.

Comment: problem here is we need to generate two apks pointing to debug and release but we only need to send one apk

Comment: Solved your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Since strings.xml in your apk will be changed so it will be two different apk for staging and production (different sha256 sum).

If it is not a problem then you can use "flavor" for two different environments.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#flavor-dimensions

If it is necessary to have only one apk for staging and production then you can add some kind of killswitch. For example it may be a file with special name. If the file is exist on device then apk use staging path in other way apk use production way.

Hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should let the user choose the environment at runtime.

For that, you should read the environment option from the shared preferences.

The easiest way would be to create a [Preferences Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) which would have a checkbox to select whether use production or staging environment. Then, map the logic to use the appropriate base URL for when the checkbox is checked or not.